# Best way to cast server viewmodel to client's - Knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm looking the best way to get my server model mapped into the knockout viewmodel
for this purpose here I'm using the mapping plugin,

Id, Title, People were mapped to something similar to the groupViewModel I have here,
How can I be sure and force this mapping to always be casted exactly to a new groupViewModel, the real issue here is **Id, Title, People** are bound to the view, not the **addPerson** method,
Please share the best workaround on this, or any better way you know to make it thiis mapping precise and yet simple and clean, thanks.

here our viewModel contains Groups Array, how to cast this Groups array into GroupViewModel items , maybe the question could be answered this way.

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

$(function() {

    var root = this;
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model, root);
    // there are Groups as expected but not the addPerson
    // will cause undefined exception

    var groupViewModel = function (item) {
        var self = this;
        self.Id = ko.observable(item.Id);
        self.Title = ko.observable(item.Title);
        self.People = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.addPerson = function (name) {
            console.log('addPerson Clicked');
        }; // .bind(self)
    }
    ko.mapping.fromJS(viewModel);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Edit - Updated based to the answer :

**Server ViewModel**

```
In Server we have this :

    class ServerVm {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public IList<GroupMap> Groups { get; set; } // groupViewModel
}
```

In the client we have :

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

$(function() {

    var root = this;
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model, root);

    //viewModel.Groups = ko.observableArray([]);
    // No need because it's same as server model

    viewModel.addGroup = function (teamName) {
            console.log('addGroup Clicked');
    }; // .bind(self)       
    // addGroup is fine
    // it's defined here and working fine, no special mapping needed here

    // "model" contains something
    var groupViewModel = function (item) {
        var self = this;
        self.Id = ko.observable(item.Id);
        self.Title = ko.observable(item.Title);
        self.People = ko.observableArray([]);
        // self.addPerson - this is hidden in the "model"
        self.addPerson = function (name) {
            console.log('addPerson Clicked');
        }; // .bind(self)
    }
    ko.mapping.fromJS(viewModel);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Our problem is the `self.addPerson` located inside our nested collection which because the container(groupViewModel) isn't bound automatically to the GroupMap. everytime I create groupViewModel by hand it's ok cause I'm casting it myself, but this is not the real mapping solution, what's yours, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use different overload of `ko.mapping.fromJS` method that takes 3 parameters, from [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html):

> **Specifying the update target**
>   ...The third parameter to ko.mapping.fromJS indicates the target.
>   *ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, someObject);*

So in your case you could update your view model definition as follows:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;    
    this.addPerson = function(data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: ...+ self.Id,
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: "POST",
            success: function (result) // result
            {
                console.log('Success');
                var avm = new childViewModel(result,self); // another defined vm
                self.People.push(avm);
            }
        });
    }
}
ViewModel.prototype.init = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
}
```

And to initialize it:

```
...
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
...
var vm = new ViewModel();
vm.init(model);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

See working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eemouquc/3/).

Another approach, a bit shorter, is to map your model first and then add methods to it, like this:

```
var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);
vm.addPerson = function(data) {
...
```

See another [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eemouquc/4/).

I like first approach more since function is defined inside view model and not added later.

**Update:**

So, after some clarification in comments and after question update, here is what should be done:

1. You should use mentioned `ko.mapping.fromJS` method inside that child object to map it's properties automatically.
2. You should use mapping object to tell the `mapping` plugin how to map your child object.

The child object view model:

```
function groupViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    self.addPerson = function(personData) {
        // here should be your ajax request, I'll use dummy data again        
    };    
}
```

The mapping object:

```
var mapping = {
    "Groups" : {
        'create': function(options) {
            return new groupViewModel(options.data);
        }
    }
};
```

And initialization:

```
var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(model, mapping);
```

Here is updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eemouquc/6/).

Comment: Thanks Ilya, While I'm looking at your code in detail to understand the differences I should say that your second approach is exactly the same as mine, here I posted an extract of my code, you did vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data); and then vm.Addsomething, this is the same as mine, there I have vm.addGroup, the problem is about the inner object when each of my groupViewModels should have addPerson, I edit my post to show what I mean

Comment: It's not the same, well at least not the same as in your current question. But I think I begin to understand what problem you have.

Comment: Ilya I think it should be so near or maybe the soltion, I should look at it more carefully some minutes later, I'll edited my old post with the data needed, Is the hint on the mapping section of your code, Thanks again dude for the great help, if there need any other hint please provide it :)

Comment: I'll update my answer according to your new code and my last solution from comment above, so answer would be correct.

Comment: @LastBye - done, I've updated my answer, now should be clear how to use.

Comment: smart answer by a smart guy, extreme help, extra information wasn't necessary cause I got the point. thanks again, unfortunately can't vote it up more :D

Comment: @LastBye, you're welcome! I posted the update in case someone else would face similar problem. Anyway, glad to help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60689/discussion-between-lastbye-and-ilya-luzyanin).

Comment: could you please join me in the chat

Comment: Hi Ilya, sorted out the last issue I mentioned, now there seems to be another small issue to continue which I opened a new question, http://stackoverflow.com/q/25748258/50506 , please take a look at, thanks